# Repulsion Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sfml

I am trying to implement a basic AI for a Turrets game in SFML and C++ and I have some problems.
This AI follows some waypoints stablished in a Bezier Courve. 
In first place, this path was followed only by one enemy. For this purpose, the enemy has to calculate his distance between his actual position
to the next waypoint he has to pick.
If the distance is less than a specific value we stablish, then, we get to the next point. This will repeat until the final destination is reached. (in the submitting code, forget about the var m_go)

Okay, our problem gets when we spawn several enemies and all have to follow the same path, because it produces a bad visual effect (everyone gets upside another).
In order to solve this visual problem, we have decided to use a repulsion vector. The calculus gets like this: [representation of what we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOMr1.png)

As you can see, we calculate the repulsion vector with the inverse of the distance between the enemy and his nearest neighbor.
Then, we get it applying this to the "theorical" direction, by adding it, and we get a resultant, which is the direction that
our enemy has to follow to not "collide" with it's neighbors.
But, our issue comes here: 
The enemys get sepparated in the middle of the curve and, as we spawn more enemys, the speed of all of them increases dramatically (including the enemies that don't calculate the repuslion vector).

1 - Is it usual that this sepparation occours in the middle of the trajectory?

2 - Is it there a way to control this direction without the speed getting affected?

3 - Is it there any alternative to this theory?

I submit the code below (There is a variable in Spanish [resultante] which it means resultant in English):

```
if (!m_pathCompleted) {
    if (m_currentWP == 14 && m_cambio == true) {
        m_currentWP = 0;
        m_path = m_pathA;
        m_cambio = false;
    }

    if (m_neighbors.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_neighbors.size(); i++) {
            if (m_enemyId != m_neighbors[i]->GetId()) {

                float l_nvx = m_neighbors[i]->GetSprite().getPosition().x - m_enemySprite.getPosition().x;
                float l_nvy = m_neighbors[i]->GetSprite().getPosition().y - m_enemySprite.getPosition().y;
                float distance = std::sqrt(l_nvx * l_nvx + l_nvy * l_nvy);

                if (distance < MINIMUM_NEIGHBOR_DISTANCE) {
                    l_nvx *= -1;
                    l_nvy *= -1;

                    float l_vx = m_path[m_currentWP].x - m_enemySprite.getPosition().x;
                    float l_vy = m_path[m_currentWP].y - m_enemySprite.getPosition().y;

                    float l_resultanteX = l_nvx + l_vx;
                    float l_resultanteY = l_nvy + l_vy;

                    float l_waypointDistance = std::sqrt(l_resultanteX * l_resultanteX + l_resultanteY * l_resultanteY);

                    if (l_waypointDistance < MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {
                        if (m_currentWP == m_path.size() - 1) {
                            std::cout << "\n";
                            std::cout << "[GAME OVER]" << std::endl;
                            m_go = false;
                            m_pathCompleted = true;
                        } else {
                            m_currentWP++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (l_waypointDistance > MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {
                        l_resultanteX = l_resultanteX / l_waypointDistance;
                        l_resultanteY = l_resultanteY / l_waypointDistance;
                        m_enemySprite.move(ENEMY_SPEED * l_resultanteX * dt, ENEMY_SPEED * l_resultanteY * dt);
                    }

                } else {

                    float vx = m_path[m_currentWP].x - m_enemySprite.getPosition().x;
                    float vy = m_path[m_currentWP].y - m_enemySprite.getPosition().y;
                    float len = std::sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);

                    if (len < MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {
                        if (m_currentWP == m_path.size() - 1) {
                            std::cout << "\n";
                            std::cout << "[GAME OVER]" << std::endl;
                            m_go = false;
                            m_pathCompleted = true;
                        } else {
                            m_currentWP++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (len > MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {
                        vx = vx / len;
                        vy = vy / len;
                        m_enemySprite.move(ENEMY_SPEED * vx * dt, ENEMY_SPEED * vy * dt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        float vx = m_path[m_currentWP].x - m_enemySprite.getPosition().x;
        float vy = m_path[m_currentWP].y - m_enemySprite.getPosition().y;

        float len = std::sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);

        if (len < MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {
            if (m_currentWP == m_path.size() - 1) {
                std::cout << "\n";
                std::cout << "[GAME OVER]" << std::endl;
                m_go = false;
                m_pathCompleted = true;
            } else {
                m_currentWP++;
            }
        }

        if (len > MINIMUM_WAYPOINT_DISTANCE) {

            vx = vx / len;
            vy = vy / len;

            m_enemySprite.move(ENEMY_SPEED * vx * dt, ENEMY_SPEED * vy * dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions one by one, but first, I don't see anything terribly wrong in the code, so it could be simply a set of non contemplated situations.

> 1 - Is it usual that this sepparation occours in the middle of the
>   trajectory?

Well, you're applying repulsion forces to every enemy based on distance of *near enough* others. If something weird happens or if you're moving them more than necessary, could result on a considerable deviation from their original trajectory.

> 2 - Is it there a way to control this direction without the speed
>   getting affected?

In this line

`m_enemySprite.move(ENEMY_SPEED * l_resultanteX * dt, ENEMY_SPEED * l_resultanteY * dt);`

we see you're, in fact, applying that repulsion force based on `l_resultante` vector. That vector depends directly on `l_nv` (repulsion vector), which its module (or *length*) is **proportional** to the distance between `this` (enemy you are processing now) and `other` (the neighbor). As you're multiplying this vector by the speed of  the enemy (a constant value), greater the distance, greater the force applied and more separation will be between them.

I suggest you to:

- *Normalize the vector* `l_nv` (**Easier**): This is, force it to have module 1. With this solution every enemy will be pushed with the same force (basically `ENEMY_SPEED`) but in proper direction.
- *Inverse the vector* `l_nv` (**Little harder**): If you apply this vector inversely proportional to the distance (module = 1/distance), they will behave the opposite and they will be pushed less if they are farther from each other.

Also consider that you are applying forces consecutively and you're making them *effective* by every neighbor processed. This implies something undesirable. If you push an enemy, this force could move it into a location where a future enemy (in the for loop) could push it maybe more than before. If this effect concatenates several times, could trigger a **chain reaction** where your enemy is pushed more and more. This effect will be amplified if you're applying the forces proportional to the distance.

> 3 - Is it there any alternative to this theory?

*I actually run out of ideas, but I left this space here if someone want to edit the answer and suggest something*

Comment: Thank you for your  answer!! But I'm still not understanding why when I spawn two enemies everything is okey, but when I spawn another one, increases the speed of all of them when they are dar away even if I'm checking that this repulsion vector is applied only to the enemies that are closer than the minimum distance I specified.

Comment: Did you try any debugging? May help a little to draw a circle around each enemy to see where the repulsion area starts and also some arrows representing the repulsion vector